# Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager'

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, error-handling, thymeleaf

I faced a problem after trying to add annotation-driven/ to my dispatcher-servlet.xml file. Everything was working before, but after trying to enable my app validation with bindingResult one problem occurred.
Problem: bindingResut was unable to detect error. I searched many answers, but non of them was helpful. I found one solution to add  annotation-driven/. Now I have this:
Error:

```
Lie 22, 2016 12:53:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcContentNegotiationManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/MethodClassKey
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/MethodClassKey
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getCacheKey(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:126)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.getTransactionAttribute(AbstractFallbackTransactionAttributeSource.java:86)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.matches(TransactionAttributeSourcePointcut.java:41)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:211)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:248)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.MethodClassKey
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 34 more
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model  <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /> -->
    <annotation-driven />




<!--    <beans:bean id="usercontroller" class="com.javatechig.controller.UserController">
        <beans:property name="controller" ref="controller"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="userservice" class="services.UserService">
        <beans:property name="service" ref="service"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean> -->

    <beans:bean id="templateResolver"
      class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
       <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
  <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
</beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean  id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="order" value="1"/>
    <beans:property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"/> <!-- THIS -->
</beans:bean>






    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />






    <context:component-scan base-package="com.javatechig.controller" />
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->






</web-app>
```

Dependecies:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt0gh.png)

Comment: have you tried to move up your 2 last tags :  <tx:annotation [...] and <context:component-scan [... ] . try to implement them right below the : <annotation-driven /> tag.

Comment: I don't know what to say..... You're the man!!!!!

Comment: Can you please explain me why this thing happened ?

Comment: I cant tell why. I just experienced this problem in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to move up your 2 last tags : `<tx:annotation [...]` and `<context:component-scan [... ]` . try to implement them right below the : `<annotation-driven />` tag.